# Laravel HTTP Client - LinkedIn Authentication - A required parameter "grant_type" is missing

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Greetings fellow developers,

So I am trying to retrive an access token from linkedin over Laravel with HTTP Client (Guzzle).

I'm using the following code:

```
$request = Http::asForm()->post("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => config('services.linkedin.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.linkedin.client_secret'),
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
            ]
        ])->json();
```

The problem is that instead of the getting the token, I am getting this:

```
array:2 [
  "error" => "invalid_request"
  "error_description" => "A required parameter "grant_type" is missing"
]
```

I've already tried all possible combinations I can remember, but I'm officially stuck.

Has anyone achieved this before? Or has any tips on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: as a user mentioned, you are sending `form_params` when you should just send the content....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```php
Http::asForm()->post("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", [
    'client_id' => config('services.linkedin.client_id'),
    'client_secret' => config('services.linkedin.client_secret'),
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
]);
```

You shouldn't need the `form_params` wrapper